# Testng soft assertion doesn't wrok as expected

Tags: java, testng

I was asked this testng question in an interview. I answered this as first test will fail and second will pass.
But to my surprize when I run in an intelliJ idea. I could see that both fail.

For second test the expected value is shown as "values". Can't figure out why?

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.SoftAssert;

public class SoftAssertion{

SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

@Test
public void first(){
 softAssert.assertEquals("values", "value");
 softAssert.assertAll();
}

@Test
public void second(){
 softAssert.assertEquals("value", "value");
 softAssert.assertAll();
}

}
```

I am using testng 7.1.0

[Test Run Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvRUZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created `SoftAssert` as a class member, thus both tests operate with the same instance and you accumulate soft assertions in the same object. When you call `assertAll()` in the second test, the first failed assertion already collected. And here we go.

So it is a mistake to create `SoftAssert` instance on an object level. It should be created within a method.

However, there is still one possible side effect: TestNG does not guarantee the order of test methods execution, so if the `second()` test executes first, you'll see one failed and one passed.

Comment: Hi @Yevhen, sorry it was a typo. I have edited the code.Can I just conclude that SoftAssert as well assertAll()  should be used at method level only? And this question asked was just to trick me?

Comment: @MotivatedMind, I tend to think so. SoftAssert supposed to be used in one scope and not being shared between different test methods. Of course, it is possible, but it is bad practice.